# Issue with table on mail servers

Tags: php, email

I am making promotion emails for my commerce, making querys and building a table to be send inside an email; on my localhost the design seems correct with no problems, but on gmail/outlook(hotmail) the table gets modified.

[image: Normal Output]

Too simple, I would like to use an image with url, so re-direct the user to the item, I would like something like this:

[image: Desired output]

But for some reason I receive this on my mails and the imagepath receives an additional "!" (image!_path/name.jpg | it should be image_path/name.jpg)

[image: Issue]

this is the code I am using for inside a loop to get the items to build the table

```
<table>
<tr><td><img src='image_url' alt='$imagen_thumb' width='100px' height='100px' />
</td></tr><tr><td>
<p style='text-align: justify;'>$desc</p></td></tr>
<tr style='text-align:center;'><td><b>$$price</b></td></tr>
<tr style='text-align:center;'><td>
<a href='urltoitem' target='_blank'><img src='urltoimage'/></a></td></tr>    
</table>
```

This issue only appears on the emails but on my localhost seems correct, is this issue about the code or about the mail server that for some reason "modifies" the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the dimensions(heights and width) of each row and column(i.e.  & ). Since you haven't specified that, the email picks the random dimension

Comment: Yep that helped but the imagepath still changes

Comment: How do you build your image url?

Comment: <img src="http://mypage.com/$imagen_thumb" alt='$imagen_thumb' width='100px' height='100px' />

Comment: for some reason, one button image url changes and the other one an ! is included, dunno why, just 2 images, the rest work fine

Comment: A good test would be to hard code the image url and see if the mail/server updates it... That is  
<img src="mypage.com/name.jpg"; alt='$imagen_thumb' width='100px' height='100px' />

Comment: This is a bit creepy, I tried what you suggest but now one url is changed to http://! and an "!" appeared inside the email, on localhost obviously works fine

Comment: Weird, at least we know it's something the server does. Try to include a full qualified link. I think it will solve your issue.That is <img src="http://www.mypage.com/name.jpg"; alt='$imagen_thumb' width='100px' height='100px' />